# Android: gradlew does not work until accessed from AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

Issue: The project always fails when I try to execute 'gradlew build' on a fresh git clone from CLI. It says a certain build tool is missing. But once I open the same project from AndroidStudio, 'gradlew build' works perfectly both within AndroidStudio and on CLI.

I checked 'git status' and found changes in 
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml

I also tried committing these changes and retrying the steps over again.
Still gradlew was not working until the project was opened once in AndroidStudio.

Is this how it is supposed to work, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The clone did not know where the SDK was located, hence the issue. Once I added the SDK location through `local.properties`, the issue was resolved

As the file was in `.gitignore`, it was not part of the project inside the repository.